# Continuity of function defined on $C_c(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, continuity

Let $X=C_c(\mathbb{R})$, the space of functions with compact support, normed with the sup norm. Define $ f: (X, \vert \vert.\vert \vert_{\infty} )\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as $  f= \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} x(t)dt \>\>\> \forall x \in X$
Then $f$ is continuous(T/F).

I think function is not cts but I can't construct a counterexample.

Answer (score 2):

Take $x_n \in C_c(\mathbb{R})$ such that 
$$x_n(t) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{n} & x \in [-n,n] \\ -\frac{1}{n}(x-n+1) &x \in (n, n+1] \\ - \frac{1}{n}(x+n-1) & x \in [-n-1, -n) \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}.\end{cases}$$

Then $x_n \to 0$ in $\| \cdot \|_\infty$ (that is $x_n$ tends to $0$ uniformly), but 
$$f(x_n) >\frac{1}{n}\cdot 2n = 2$$
for all $n$. Thus $f$ is not sequentially continuous (we have a sequence $x_n \to 0$ such that $f(x_n) \not\to f(0)$), which is equivalent to continuity for metric spaces.

Comment: I am sorry but can you tell me how you think this type of counterexample.

Comment: Since $f$ is linear, I thought of whether or not $f$ was continuous as a linear functional (i.e., is a bounded linear functional). One of the ways to check this property is to see whether or not there is a sequence $x_n \to 0$ such that $|f(x_n)|$ is bounded below by some $\delta>0$ for all $n$. This is what I constructed in my proof. As to why I suspected it's not continuous, well, the answer to that is in my answer. You can integrate very small things over very big sets to get something not so small.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $\|f\|\leq M$ for some $M>0$, then for all $x\in C_{c}({\bf{R}})$ with $\|x\|_{\infty}\leq 1$, one has $|f(x)|\leq M$. Now find some $x\in C_{c}({\bf{R}})$ such that $0\leq x\leq 1$ and that $x=1$ on $[-M,M]$, then $|f(x)|\geq\displaystyle\int_{-M}^{M}x(t)dt=2M$ but $\|x\|_{\infty}=1$.